# tossing a die until we get some numbers

Tags: probability

We toss a fair die until we get each of the numbers $2$, $4$ and $5$ at least once.

Let $X$ be the number of tosses required.

Find $P(X=5)$

I got $\dfrac{3.194}{6^5}$ with 
$3.194=3[{3 \choose 2} 4!+{3 \choose 1}\frac{4!}{2!}+2{3 \choose 1}\frac{4!}{2!}+2\cdot \frac{4!}{3!}+\frac{4!}{2!2!}]$

Comment: Seems simple enough.  What problem are you having?

Comment: can you just write result so I can see ıf I solved it correctly? I got 194/6^5

Comment: I think you ought to show your work so we could point out any problems, rather than asking people to do it all over again.

Comment: I think that it is better just writing the result so people can think about it. I am wondering whether 194/6^5 is correct or not. Thanks

Comment: The 6^5 in your answer presumably came from five rolls, how did you come up with the 194 part?  People on this site are generally much more willing to help when they can see that the question asker has made a good effort to work through a problem and is willing to share their work.

Comment: $194=(3 choose 2) 4!+(3 choose 1) 4!/2! +  2(3 choose 1) 4!/2!+ 2. 4!/3! +4!/2!2! $

Comment: $194$ looks too small to me, by a factor of about $3$

Comment: I can not tell what you are trying to count.

Answer (score 1):

To have X=5 two of the three numbers must occure at least once each amongst the first four rolls and the third only then on the fifth roll.

Count ways to select and arrange

- two singles from the three and two others
- two singles from the three and one other as a double
- one single and one double from the three and one other
- two doubles from the three
- a triple and a single from the three

Sum and divide by $6^5$

---

Alternatively, use the principle of inclusion and exclusion. Count ways to select the fifth result and the other four so that the other two numbers are not missed among them.